# Finding words containing two font sizes in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Example: I copy text from a PDF file to MsWord. All text is font 14 but word "LOVE"

"L" is size 14

"OVE" is size 9

I'm looking to find that words like that. Can anyone help me? Using VBA Code. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the format isn't initial caps?

Comment: The format in original pdf file is allcaps. I sure. Some allcaps words has two font, so i want to find its and replace it. If look on msword, it like smallcaps font but not

Comment: Is there a point to this? A simple Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.Reset or equivalent will restore all of a paragraph's content to the underlying Style's format. Alternatively, for just the font size, you could use code like: With Selection.Paragraphs(1):   .Range.Font.Size = .Style.Font.Size: End With

Answer (score 0):

The [.Font.Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.font.size) property is useful in this case. It returns "9999999" if the word has mixed font sizes.

```
Sub CheckFonts()

  Dim objSingleWord As Range
  Dim objDoc As Document
  
  Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
 
  With objDoc
    For Each objSingleWord In .Words
        Debug.Print objSingleWord.Text; objSingleWord.Font.Size
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not work. i use ms word 2003, it not return 999999